# Array of arrays to array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, object

```
const events = [
        [{
          createdAt: "2021-12-06T16:32:59.260Z"
    location: "Off-Site"
    name: "Viewing"
        }],
        [{
          createdAt: "2021-12-06T16:32:59.260Z"
```

...
}],

```
    ..........
]
```

Hi I have question. From the above can i be able to convert the data to somethin like

```
const events = [
        {
          createdAt: "2021-12-06T16:32:59.260Z"
    location: "Off-Site"
        },
        {
          createdAt: "2021-12-06T16:32:59.260Z"
```

...
},

```
    ..........
]
```

if anyone knows please answer

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method

> The flat() method creates a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated into it recursively up to the specified dept

```js
const arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5]];

const res = arr.flat()

console.log(res)
```